# Django - DATE_FORMAT - I can't force Django to use a Date format

Tags: django, date, datetime, django-settings

I'm having a problem with Date Formats.

I'm from Argentina and here we use the Date Format dd/mm/yyyy.

When I use a computer configured in Spanish language I see the dates and the date inputs perfect, for example in a detail view I see this in a date dd/mm/yyy, but on a computer like my own one I see this as mm/dd/yyyy

This generates a problem with my forms, in a specific case on my app when I go to save in the database a date input 03/01/2017 (Jan. 3. 2017) saves March 1 2017.

This is the configuration on the settings file

```
USE_L10N = False
DATE_FORMAT = 'd/m/Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('d/m/Y')

USE_TZ = True
```

I only use DATE_FORMAT too, TZ False.

I really don't know if is any way to force Django to use the format dd/mm/yyyy for all the cases.